# Локация по произвольному IP адресу через Yandex Maps API

Tags: yandex-maps-api, geoip

Всем привет!

Надо в пост обработке запросов на бэкенде получить из клиентского IP(v4/v6) страну и город. Увы, покупной [MaxMind GeoIP](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-databases) использовать нет возможности,а GeoLite, по отзывам, не очень справляется со своей задачей. На проекте используется фронтом Yandex Maps. Вот поэтому задумался, можно ли использовать их для получения локации по IP.

У Yandex есть JS API, по которому можно получить координаты пользователя через [ymaps.geolocation.get(...)](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/geolocation#get). Но проблема в том, что этот метод не принимает IP. Есть еще [HTTP API Геокодера](https://yandex.ru/dev/geocode/doc/ru/request?) - но через него также не запросить локацию по IP.

Наверное, Yandex Maps API можно использовать на фронте и к запросами клиента добавлять локацию, но тогда придется что-то придумывать, если появятся мобильные приложения. Поэтому, кажется, что разумно было бы реализовать такое преобразование в одном месте(в бэкенде).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность с Yandex Maps получить локацию по IP, или возможные альтернативные пути для коммерческой разработки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте для определения координат по ip-адресу [Локатор](https://yandex.ru/dev/locator/). А после кидайте координаты в функцию [geocode() JS API Яндекс карт](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/geocode) с показом результата на небольшой карте. Такой сценарий у Яндекса бесплатен.